# Why to TikzCD arrows behave differently when made thicker compared to Tikz arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

Piggybacking off my previous question [TikzCD arrow "to path" tracing a path over nodes with sharper corners (i.e. how to change looseness)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636200/tikzcd-arrow-to-path-tracing-a-path-over-nodes-with-sharper-corners-i-e-how)

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd} 
L\tikzmark{L}\arrow[dd, color = red, shift right = 1.2pt] \arrow[d, "a", thick, color = red!50!blue]  \arrow[r, "l", hook, shift left=1pt]   & \tikzmark{M}M  \arrow[ldd, "h", shift right = 1pt]\arrow[ld, "j \circ h"', dashed, outer sep = -2pt, pos = 0.35] \\
A\tikzmark{A}\arrow[d, "i", hook] \arrow[loop, "\id_A", distance=8pt, out=195, in=155, color = black!30!white] \\
I\tikzmark{I}\arrow[u, "j", bend left, color = blue]                                     
\end{tikzcd}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red, ->, rounded corners]([shift={(1.6mm,.8mm)}]pic cs:L)to([shift={(.9mm,.8mm)}]pic cs:M)to([shift={(.3mm,4.2mm)}]pic cs:I);
\draw[red!50!blue, thick, ->, rounded corners]([shift={(1.6mm,.4mm)}]pic cs:L)to([shift={(.6mm,.4mm)}]pic cs:M)to([shift={(1.3mm,3.5mm)}]pic cs:A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces something along the lines of

[image]

I have made the two purple arrows thicker, and I find the one made using `\draw` acceptable, but the one made using `\arrow` unacceptable (the head is too thick).

**My questions are: why are the arrows in TikzCD different from those of Tikz (they look the same when used normally, just when thickened differences appear), and what is a good way to fix this (I suppose I can use `\draw` for the other purple arrow as well, but that feels pretty stupid)**

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. I'm assuming you're missing `\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}`. If you use `amsmath`, the code `\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}` is probably preferred.

Comment: ahh, my bad. That part of the code is inessential and can be ignored; I forgot that that wasn't a default operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You need to add the arrowtype `->` to the command to have it size properly.

`\arrow[->, d, "a", thick, color = red!50!blue]`

Comment: Is there a reason why this is not the default, instead of the current default?